# C-) not recognized on Windows 10

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows, keystrokes, prefix-keys

In my `init` file, I have `C-)` bound to a `smartparens` "slurp" command. This works great on linux, but when I try to use the same keybinding on my Windows machine, nothing happens.

To troubleshoot on my Windows machine, I've tried `C-h c` followed by `C-)`—emacs doesn't register that any keys have been hit.

I've tried a couple of similar key sequences: `M-)` and `C-0` both register fine.

Any idea why `C-)` doesn't register, and any idea how to fix it?

Comment: First, does it happen with no init file (emacs -Q)?  Second, does windows use C-) for something else, which prevents it from reaching emacs?

Comment: Are you using the GUI version of emacs?

Comment: @Dan, it happens with no init file. I looked at a page of [windows shortcuts here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/126449/keyboard-shortcuts-for-windows), and C-) isn't on the list.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10, yes I'm using the GUI version.

Comment: Please show your code that binds the key sequence. Provide a step-by-step recipe that starts from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: Hi @Drew,
On linux I can just do the following:
1. `emacs -Q`
2. Run `eval-last-sexp` on `(global-set-key (kbd "C-)") 'execute-command))` 
It then works great.
If I do that on Windows, nothing happens. The code evaluates fine, but either Windows or Emacs can't see the `C-)` key sequence when those keys are pressed.

Comment: I see. Sorry, but I don't have an answer. I see the same thing, and I haven't been able to find info about it. The key is definitely bound in the keymap, but it seems that it is not being sent by the keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution—the following works for me:
`Control Panel` > 
`Language` > 
`Advanced Settings` > 
`Change language bar hot keys` > 
Ensure `Between input languages` is highlighted > 
`Change Key Sequence...` >
Change `Switch Keyboard Layout` from `Ctrl + Shift` to `Not Assigned`.

A similar process is outlined [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leo-editor/XqAQ48gE40Y).

Comment: I had this issue even though I had done these steps in the past. Something must have gotten messed up in Windows because I had to add the key binding back and then remove it to get C-) working again. Oddly C-( worked, but C-) didn't.

Comment: @Tanj have the same issue here...